# Understanding a basic thing with Auto-Layout

Tags: ios, objective-c

Using Xcode 5, I used to put views on the storyboard, and they just worked. I didn't have to set their width and height constraints, just their size in the storyboard. In Xcode 6 if I don't give views width/height constraints, they become huge. (Why??)

The real question is, if there is a magic button, than you can order anything on the screen, and than just let Xcode scale everything according to screens without constraints. Just take all sizes, and distances, and change them in relative to the new screen size.

To illustrate my problem, please take a look at this image:
[image]

I'm trying to place two buttons in the centre y, and centre x of the screen.
so that Y1=Y2 , AND X1=X2 .

I set their width and height constraints, I set the left view's `leading space to container` constraint, and the right view's `trailing space to container` constraint.

Same for their top space to container constraints (Y1 AND Y2).

What happens is that x1 and x2 becomes consts variables, and in the iPhone 5 simulator it looks as expected, but in bigger screens, I see the squares overlapping and d is probably very small.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How do I get the desired behaviour?
3. Why you can't just put them on screen and let Xcode change relatively all sizes and distances according to screen?

Comment: Can you post what your specific constraints are?

Comment: @AaronBrager I wrote my constrains in the question, they are width/height, and top left right bottom (where you control drag and chose leading space from superview etc).

Comment: Are they equality or inequality constraints? What are they (in)equal to? What are their priorities?

Comment: @AaronBrager they are equally and priority 1000. I dont get it, why do i have to answer such hard questions in order to put 2 poor squares on screen? can you explain to me how to do that, and ignore the way i did it ? i will just copy exactly what you say to Xcode .

Comment: Something is very strange , if i  take the left square and put it closer to the left edge = x1 smaller, than its position great on any screen, but if i take it to the right, with bigger x1, than in iPhone6+ its becomes much bigger and the square is out of screen. I AM LOST.

Comment: You must have other constraints that you're not mentioning, or some other incorrect settings or code that is modifying something. I made a new single view project, and added two squares. They both have width and height constraints of 100 points, top constraints of 20 points, and leading/trailing constraints of 20 points. The app works perfectly on 6 and 6+ simulators.

Comment: @AaronBrager thanks a lot . please see my answer and if you can help me understand fundamental things .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For achieving this, Do the following:

1. Before adding any constraints, Embed these two buttons in a view(eg. named:button container view)
2. Add Center Horizontally to container and Center Vertically to Container constraints between button container view to super view.
3. Set Width, Height constraints to the button container view.

This keeps the space between two buttons`(d)` constantly and keeps always `X1, X2` to be equal. And it works in both portrait and landscape mode.

Refer this screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem   .

I set width and height constrains, than i set for each button , a constrain to centre it vertically and horizontally , that puts both of then in the right position for every phone .

by center i mean i control drag and chose center to superView . than my constrain is

```
align center x to superview equals 82
```